# Is there any cost for using Push Notification Service?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any cost for using the Push Notification Service?

I know it requires using my own server to send notifications, but the signals are passed through an Apple server. There are no server transfer fees?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there is no cost. The only "gotchas" are that your app has to be in the app store(i.e. no jailbroken apps), and you have to maintain a server for pushing the events.

Comment: Can we do it for Enterprise apps?

Comment: -@Mike, how much does the "push" server cost per month?

Comment: The other __gotcha__ is you have to pay for your APNS server's exec time, data access, storage space etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you are building you own push server, which you mention above, there are hosting expenses and the cost of time to set up and administer it.  Alternatively, you can use a service like iLime ([www.ilime.com)](http://www.ilime.com), which provides a RESTful API and a lot of free push alerts up-front to handle the server infrastructure for you.

Disclosure: I work for KeyLimeTie, who produces iLime - let me know if you have any questions.

Best wishes integrating APNS into your app, however you choose to do so.

Tim

Comment: Seems iLime will be phasing out their service; please refrain from advertising here.