# can iPhone application use push service if deployed via enterprise deployment?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Based on following question

[push notification service cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144678/is-there-any-cost-for-using-push-notification-service)

I want to know, will my application receive push notifications if it is deployed via Enterprise deployment, and is there any limit of number of installations of enterprise deployment for push notifications, we currently have 10000+ users, but the application is only for the members and god knows if apple rejects it to put it on appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications work with Ad Hoc distribution; I don't see why Enterprise distribution would be significantly different.