# APNS Free Notifications Limit

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Is there a limit on number of free APNS notifications that can be sent before it becomes paid or is it unlimited free notifications? Some reference to Apple doc on this would be helpful.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any cost for using Push Notification Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144678/is-there-any-cost-for-using-push-notification-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not from Apple.

Apple used to say this on their website, but have subsequently changed their wording:

[image: Push is free]

If you're using a 3rd party to send these messages, then there might be. E.g. [Urban Airship](https://go.urbanairship.com/accounts/register) currently offer:

Push Notifications
1 Million FREE Push messages/month. $0.001 per additional Push message. $0.0025 per every Rich Push message.

Comment: I'm not looking at 3rd party services. I tried searching the apple site for any comment on limit. I'm looking for some official doc which either says its free or mentions the charges to reassure a client.

Comment: It used to say this on Apple's website, but their wording has subsequently changed "Push notifications are free. Your app cannot charge customers for the use of push notifications." See https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Push+notifications+are+free.+Your+app+cannot+charge+customers+for+the+use+of+push+notifications (top result in Google)

Comment: Also, you can look at Apple's guide for push. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/RemoteNotificationsPG.pdf

Comment: Google result shows those wordings but the linked page does not. Also, I couldn't find anything related to free / charges in the documentation link. I'll mark you answer as accepted, but if you come across the required URL anywhere plz post it here. Thanks :)